# R Separating column values using tidyr's separate, but the values are in nested list

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr, tidyverse, r-sf

I am reading the book ggplot2 written by Hadley Wickham, and following the codes. However, the USAboundaries package is not working in the way as it is shown in the book.
In the book, the codes work like this:

```
library(USAboundaries)
c18 <- us_boundaries(as.Date("1820-01-01"))
c18df <- fortify(c18)
#> Regions defined for each Polygons
head(c18df)
#> long lat order hole piece id group
#> 1 -87.6 35 1 FALSE 1 4 4.1
#> 2 -87.6 35 2 FALSE 1 4 4.1
#> 3 -87.6 35 3 FALSE 1 4 4.1
#> 4 -87.6 35 4 FALSE 1 4 4.1
#> 5 -87.5 35 5 FALSE 1 4 4.1
#> 6 -87.3 35 6 FALSE 1 4 4.1
ggplot(c18df, aes(long, lat)) +
 geom_polygon(aes(group = group), colour = "grey50", fill = NA) +
 coord_quickmap()
```

However, when I am running the same codes in RStudio, the data frame is totally different:
The long and lat values are vectorized in nested list such as:

```
geometry
list(list(c(-88.0746219415898, -88.3133290074677, ...)))
list(list(c(-96.7247616421399, -96.0010234528651, ...)))
...
...
```

... means there are many many values there.

Therefore, the ggplot codes above doesn't work because the data frame doesn't have long and lat.
Since there are no long and lat variable(columns), how should I create a long and lat from this data? Maybe you could install this package and try run it to see what's going on.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with the `fortify` function, but notice that the output of the `us_boundaries` should be an `sf` object, and the way to specify the date in `us_boundaries` does not require `as.Date` (see the example in `?us_boundaries`).

Since `c18` is an `sf` object, you don't have to use `geom_polygon`. As a result, I removed the `as.Date` from your code, and plot the `c18` using `ggplot` and `geom_sf`.

```
library(USAboundaries)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)

c18 <- us_boundaries("1820-01-01")

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = c18)
```

[image]

See this link to learn more about plotting the `sf` object: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/vignettes/sf5.html#ggplot2

**UPDATE**

I did more research on this issue. The `fortify` function can convert an Spatial Polygon Data Frame to a data frame. It looks like the original version of `us_boundaries` returns a Spatial Polygon Data Frame, so it is necessary to convert it to a data frame with the `fortify` function.

Below I first convert the `sf` object to a Spatial Polygon Data Frame, and then use the `fortify` function to reproduce the original process. Now we can plot `c18df` with `geom_polygon`.

```
library(USAboundaries)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)

c18 <- us_boundaries("1820-01-01")

c18spdf <- as(c18, "Spatial")

c18df <- fortify(c18spdf)

ggplot(c18df, aes(long, lat)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(group = group), colour = "grey50", fill = NA) +
  coord_quickmap()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot www! I'll definitely read the link you shared, and I really learned a lot, especially the way to examine problems, from your response!

Comment: @commentallez-vous You are welcome. Please see my update. I think I figured out how to use the `fortify` function. Please accept my post as the answer if this solves your question.

Comment: Yeah, that's really helpful! I am gonna run, check and read documentation to understand it better. Again, thank you so much for your help!